# Is there a way to append the time stamp of each command that runs as part of cmake?

Tags: cmake, ninja

I am trying to debug some issue where i suspect that build dependencies are not set properly causes issues. I want to confirm the same. for that i want to log the time with seconds of each command that gets executed as part of cmake flow.

Configure command:-

```
cmake -G Ninja -DCUTLASS_NVCC_ARCHS=80 -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON -DCUTLASS_INSTALL_TESTS=ON ^"-DCMAKE_NINJA_WHAT=ninja\ -d\ explain\ -d\ stats^" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=d:/test/worker/build-tools-main/cutlass/install -DCMAKE_TEST_INSTALL_PREFIX=d:/test/worker/build-tools-main/cutlass/install -Wno-dev d:/test/worker/test-main/cutlass
```

Build command:-

```
cmake --build . --target install --verbose
```

Is there a simple way to append the time stamp for each build command that gets executed? Do we have any flags implicit to cmake ?

Comment: append to what? log to where?

Comment: i mean the time with seconds when was the the command executed as part of cmake/ninja build.

Answer (score 0):

If you only care what `ninja` is doing you can set the `NINJA_STATUS` environment variable to your liking (see the [manual](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html)). The `%e` flag will give you the *elapsed time* since ninja was started for each step.

```
$ NINJA_STATUS="[%e: %f/%t] " ninja -j1 |cat
[0.087: 1/1714] Checking build against environment
[5.789: 2/1714] Building CXX object ...
[10.246: 3/1714] Building CXX object ...
```

If you want something different, you could (ab)use [`CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_LAUNCHER`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_LAUNCHER.html) with a wrapper.

```
$ cat /tmp/ts.sh
#!/bin/sh

date
"$@"

$ rm -rf CMakeCache.txt CMakeFiles/; cmake -GNinja -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=/tmp/ts.sh ../src
[ cmake does its thing]
$ ninja -j1 |cat
[1/1702] Checking build against environment
[2/1702] Building CXX object ...
Tue Aug  1 10:50:57 EDT 2023
[3/1702] Building CXX object ...
Tue Aug  1 10:50:59 EDT 2023
[4/1702] Building CXX object ...
Tue Aug  1 10:51:00 EDT 2023
```

You can pretty much do anything with a wrapper and `CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_LAUNCHER`, but for custom targets or commands, you'll need to modify them in your `CMakeLists.txt` file(s).

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out. since build runs in parallel thread mode. It is very difficult to debug by looking at the log. Is there a way to log the information in meaningful way ?
eg:-A message `Building CXX object X.obj` followed by Actual build command used to create the X.obj. 

From my logs, i could just see the message :- `FAILED: bin/tsolver_irs_expert.exe`, and fails the build(ninja). There is no other info about cause of the problem.

Comment: use `ninja`'s `-j` flag to control the number of parallel jobs. ie `ninja -j1` for one thread. use `ninja`'s `-v` to see verbose output from `ninja`. ie the commands the `ninja` is executing at each step. combine them and redirect output to a file to generate a step-by-step log. `ninja -v -j1 > build.log`. see [`ninja`'s manual](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html) for more options.

Comment: Is it not possible to get the order while running in parellel mode? Because running in serial mode -j1 taking long hours to complete the build.